# How to add parameter to HttpWebRequest

Tags: api, authorization, httpwebrequest, spotify, credentials

I'm trying to get some data from Spotify's API, but I receive some errors from compilator and I think it may happen because I didn't add parameter *grant_type=client_credentials*.

The question is how can I add this parameter into `HttpWebRequest` object?

```cs
var token = GetToken();
var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp($"{BaseAddress}search?q=Batman&type=playlist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5&access_token={token}");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + token);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the Token is where you need to add this parameter, your **GetToken** method will be sending the **Client Credentials Flow** of the **Client Id** and **Client Secret** and it is there where the **grant_type** of **client_credentials** needs to be sent as a **HttpWebRequest** with the **ContentType** of *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* this is what the documentation refers to as a **Request Body Parameter**.

I've used **HttpClient** that allows **FormUrlEncodedContent** to do this but you should be able to send that information using **HttpWebRequest** the way you are doing it with a **POST** request but the **GetToken** code will need to be modified, that isn't shown in the question